# Cant get JavaScript code snippet to work in the Content Editor Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am trying to modify a survey in Sharepoint 2010 using a code snippet I found online. I followed the instructions as found in this webpage:  http://robdevereaux.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/how-to-add-pictures-to-a-survey/

When I try to view the survey at the end I dont see my picture at all?  I just see the same original survey questions. Has anyone experienced this before?  I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem at all.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var className;
className = 'ms-formlabel';

var elements = new Array();
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var e = 0; e < elements.length; e++)
{
    if (elements[e].className == className)
    {

        elements[e].innerHTML = elements[e].innerHTML.replace('CAR_IMAGE','<img src="/PATHTO/IMAGE/CAR.jpg"></img>');

    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the path `/PATHTO/IMAGE/CAR.jpg` with an actual valid path where your image is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch this

```
elements[e].innerHTML = elements[e].innerHTML.replace('CAR_IMAGE','<img src="/PATHTO/IMAGE/CAR.jpg"></img>');
```

With this:

```
elements[e].innerHTML = elements[e].innerHTML.replace('CAR_IMAGE','<img src="/PATHTO/IMAGE/CAR.jpg"/>');
```

If it doesn't work replace your JS with this (use jQuery - add it to your Master Page it's very handy always):

```
$(function(){
    $('td.ms-formlabel').each(function(){ 
         $(this).html(
            $(this).html().replace('CAR_IMAGE', '<img src="/Style Library/Images/CAR.jpg"/>');
         );
    });
})
```